# Is there a way to change the transparency for a matrix question in Survey.js to show the background as per other question types?

Tags: surveyjs

Is there a separate setting in the theme to set the transparency for matrix questions in Survey.js?

See the attached image - I am unable to set the transparency like I can for other question types.

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwNvm.png)

Can't find a theme setting to support this.

Answer (score 0):

Markup of matrix question right now doesn't allow to do it in easy way. There is a corresponding issue in SurveyJS library repo - https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/issues/6468 - Matrix Semi-Transparent Colors Issue.
You can track it to be informed about the progress.